# Requires assistance with vowel checker program

Tags: python

Write a python program that asks the user for a word, then calculates and prints the vowel worth of the entered word using these instructions:
Suppose you calculate the vowel worth of a word based on the following instructions:

```
a   5 points
e   4 points
i   3 points
o   2 points
u   1 point.
```

My code:

```
word = str(input("Enter a word:"))

def vowel(Word):
    global word
    Word = word
    score = 1

    if "a" or "A" in word:
        score += 5
    elif "e" or "E" in word:
        score += 4
    elif "i" or "I" in word:
        score += 3
    elif "o" or "O" in word:
        score += 2
    elif "u" or "U" in word:
        score += 1

    print("Your word scored",score,"in the vowel checker")

print(vowel(word))
```

Edit: FOR LOOP

word = input("Enter a word:")

def vowel(Wo_rd):
    global word
    Wo_rd = word
    score = 0
    for char in word.lower():
        if char == 'a' or "A":
            score += 5
        elif char == "e" or "E":
            score += 4
        elif char == "i" or "I":
            score += 3
        elif char == "o" or "O":
            score += 2
        elif char == "u" or "U":
            score += 1
        a = "Your word scored",score," in the word checker test"
        return a

print(vowel(word))

Comment: so what code do you need assistance with?

Comment: word = str(input("Enter a word:"))

def vowel(Word):
    global word
    Word = word
    score = 1

    if "a" or "A" in word:
        score += 5
    elif "e" or "E" in word:
        score += 4
    elif "i" or "I" in word:
        score += 3
    elif "o" or "O" in word:
        score += 2
    elif "u" or "U" in word:
        score += 1
        
    print("Your word scored",score,"in the vowel checker")

print(vowel(word))

Comment: show in question your code and FULL error message (Traceback)

Comment: `if "a" in word or "A" in word:` or shorter `if "a" in word.lower():`

Comment: if a appears twice in a word are you supposed to add 10 to the score?

Comment: There is no error message. Just when i enter the word "Hello" it outputs 16, which it shouldnt

Comment: `if` and `elif` are exclusive. If one is `True`, the others aren't checked.

Comment: So they should all be IF

Comment: better use `for` to get char-by-char from word and check this char with vowel

Comment: if a appears twice in a word are you supposed to add 10 to the score?

Comment: Could you show me an example how to do it in a for loop

Comment: `for char in word.lower(): if char == 'a': ...`

Comment: A solution: `sum('uoiea'.find(x)+1 for x in word.lower())`

Comment: for char in word.lower(): if char == 'a':  i will try this. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
word = str(input("Enter a word:"))

def vowel(word):
    score = 1

    for character in word:
        character = character.lower()
        if character == 'a':
            score += 5
        elif character == 'e':
            score += 4
        elif character == 'i':
            score += 3
        elif character == 'o':
            score += 2
        elif character == 'u':
            score += 1

    print("Your word scored",score,"in the vowel checker")

vowel(word)
```

Things to note:

- In Python, strings are iterable, so you can loop over each character.
- Note that you don't have to (and shouldn't) use a `global`.
- The use of `character.lower()` simplifies our conditionals.
- Instead of printing the output in the `vowel` function, you could instead just `return score` and put the print statement in the last line.

P.S. Given the question, shouldn't a word's score start at 0, not 1?

Comment: So does your example include upper and lower case letters , or does it only accept lower case  letters, And yes you are correct in saying that the score should be 0

Comment: @JackAnderson My example works for both upper- and lower-case letters. `character = character.lower()` turns each letter into lowercase, which simplifies our conditionals. This allows us to have to check against "a", not "a" or "A" like in the original code.

Comment: It's more efficient to use `for character in word.lower():` because you only call `lower()` once that way. Of course there are other ways to improve efficiency too

Answer (score 1):

First if you are passing word to `vowel` I don't know why you use global. You are calling `vowel` inside a `print` so vowel should return a string instead of printing a string itself. Next by using a `for` loop you can check each character of the word and increment the score even if multiple occurances of a vowel appear.

```
word = str(input("Enter a word:"))

def vowel(word):
  score = 1
  for c in word:
    if "a" == c.lower():
        score += 5
    elif "e" == c.lower():
        score += 4
    elif "i" == c.lower():
        score += 3
    elif "o" == c.lower():
        score += 2
    elif "u" == c.lower():
        score += 1

  return "Your word scored "+str(score)+" in the vowel checker"

print(vowel(word))
```

Answer (score 0):

> Time complexity is important

```
for character in word:
    character = character.lower()
    if  re.match("a",character):
        score += 5
    elif re.match("e",character):
        score += 4
    elif re.match("i",character):
        score += 3
    elif re.match("o",character):
        score += 2
    elif re.match("u",character):
        score += 1

print("Your word scored",score,"in the vowel checker")
```

Enter a word:hello

pbaranay code, Your word scored 7 in the vowel checker

--- 2.4024055004119873 seconds ---

My code,Your word scored 7 in the vowel checker

--- 0.004721164703369141 seconds ---